# Meaning of "ぶえっくしょ"

Tags: meaning, slang

I came across this word (ぶえっくしょ) recently and tried looking it up on every site I knew. I assume it's slang. The line in which I first saw it is:

> 「あいつだって、いつも読んでないわけじゃ………ぶえっくしょ！！」.

As I was researching it, I saw it in two other forms:ぶえっくしょん and ぶえっくしょい (sometimes ぶえっくしょーん or ぶえっくしょーい). Does anyone know what this means and what it is? Also, does it belong to a certain dialect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like another form of はくしょん, onomatopoeia for sneezing.

Searching on Google for things like "ぶえっくしょん" "くしゃみ" seems to confirm that this is the case, although I'm not too familiar with the word myself.  I found [this page](http://www.geocities.co.jp/HeartLand-Keyaki/6064/on1004.htm), for example, where it's specifically labeled as a sneeze:

> 大野「ぶえっくしょん！（←くしゃみ）」

If I had to guess, I'd say it sounds like a bit of a louder / less subtle sneeze.  That's what it sounds like to me, anyway.